# WooCommerce checkout Postcode not updating shipping method

Tags: woocommerce

I have managed to connect shipping methods with postcodes. So when ever postcode changes the corresponding shipping method is selected. But when i change the field type of billing post code to a drop down, the shipping method doesn't get updated. I have searched for the issue and seen many questions without any answer till date.

Comment: You may need to modify Woo to achieve calculation on select box - The existing code seems like   // Provide the submit button value because wc-form-handler expects it.
   $( '<input />' ).attr( 'type', 'hidden' )
       .attr( 'name', 'calc_shipping' )
       .attr( 'value', 'x' )
       .appendTo( $form );

Comment: can you give more information

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  can you